# retrieve matrix data to twig file

Tags: entries, matrix

I create a section clientSection which I linked an matrix field like in this image:
[image: screenshot]
The field has two block types : `clientImage` which has an field `clientImage` and `clientDescription` which has an field with same name.
I want to output in twig file but I don't know how exactly

```
{% set clients = craft.entries.section('clientSection').all() %}

{% for client in clients %}
  {# display content here #}
{% endfor %}
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use your Matrix field handle (which you didn't show in your question) and replace `yourMatrixFieldHandle`:

```
{% for client in clients %}
    {{ client.title }}

    {# Get all blocks related to the client entry #}
    {% for block in client.yourMatrixFieldHandle.all() %}

        {% switch block.type %}

            {% case "clientImage" %}

                {% for image in block.clientImage.all() %}
                    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
                {% endfor %}

            {% case "clientDescription" %}

                {{ block.clientDescription }}

        {% endswitch %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Read more about [working with Matrix fields here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/matrix-fields.html#working-with-matrix-field-data)

Comment: it works! thank you very much